# My friend made a riddle I can’t solve. Wanna help?

Tags: riddle

Me and my brother turn the fishes home to his doom,  for when we work together we take his breath away, one of us is an unassuming treat, alone we do nothing but together we make a mess

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> This is referring to [fishing with coke and mentos](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unexpected/comments/dvpvjj/ah_the_old_mentos_coca_cola_trick/). Mentos is an "unassuming treat", but when coke and mentos are put together, they give off CO2, which causes "a mess", and "takes [the fish's] breath away".

Comment: What's the connection to the fish you're making there?

Comment: The O2 part from CO2 comes from the oxygen in water, so you are removing the breath (the oxygen) from the water

Comment: Could _someone_ explain the fishing angle here?  This has 11 votes as of now, so I assume at least 12 people know something that I do not.

Comment: @Sneftel, [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unexpected/comments/dvpvjj/ah_the_old_mentos_coca_cola_trick/) is the connection

Comment: @JPhi1618  It should be written "the fish's home" (i.e. the water)  not "the fishes home" which is just bad spelling and confusing.

Comment: @Mathias711 This is incorrect. The reaction between Mentos and Coke does not involve the oxygen dissolved in the water. The reaction is `H2CO3 -> H2O + CO2`. The primary effect is that nucleation sites on the Mentos drive CO2 out of solution, producing bubbles and driving the above reaction, producing more CO2.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan That's not how I read it. "Turn the fishes home to his doom" (should be their doom, as it's plural) could also be written as "Guiding the fishes home to their doom".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, some [guy on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unexpected/comments/dvpvjj/ah_the_old_mentos_coca_cola_trick/f7e9wed) said that the O2 in the water wants to stick to the CO2 so they both come out.  If this really is the answer, it's not a great riddle and it is _very_ specific to that one reddit post.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yeah, no.

Answer (score 10):

Are you

> A worm and a hook?

Me and my brother turn the fishes home to his doom,

> They’re used in conjunction to catch fish

for when we work together we take his breath away,

> Ostensibly when you catch fish you take them out of water

one of us is an unassuming treat,

> The worm is

alone we do nothing

> A worm by itself doesn’t catch a fish, and neither does an unbaited hook

but together we make a mess

> Catching the fish

Answer (score 1):

> I would say nutrients and plankton, which together cause algal blooms that deoxygenate the water and kill all the fish: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutrophication